# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3001

Tags: node.js, windows, networking

I have gone through many answers here, none of them fixed my error. Here What I have tried so far.

Environment:

```
win 10 pro v2004 build 19041.29

node v12.14.1
```

1. used `netstat -a -b` to see if this port is being used by any other process.
   No process is using this port, also tried switching the port to `3000` getting same error.
2. I use docker-desktop and wsl2, so also disabled all virtual network adapter one by one. Tried after killing all other docker services.
3. Restarted my pc.
4. Tried running `npm start` through powershell as administrator

Server.js

```
const app = require('./src/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Litening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Error:

```
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1289:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1442:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\sujeet\project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sujee\CustomerAPIs\server.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1333:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3001
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For Windows users encountering the 'EACCES: permission denied' error when attempting to bind a Node.js server to a specific port, follow these steps:

1. Run PowerShell as an Administrator:
   Ensure elevated privileges for system-level commands.
2. Stop the "winnat" service:

```
net stop winnat
```

This halts the Windows Network Address Translation (NAT) service, responsible for dynamically translating private IP addresses to public ones, essential for internet connectivity.

3. Restart the "winnat" service:

```
net start winnat
```

This command restores the `winnat` service, reestablishing NAT functionality.

**Technical Explanation:**

- **Port Binding and Permissions:**
  The 'EACCES' error arises from inadequate permissions during the attempt to bind the Node.js server to a specific IP address and port.
  Running PowerShell as an Administrator grants the necessary
  permissions for this operation.
- **Windows NAT Service ("winnat"):**
  'winnat' is a critical service responsible for network address translation. During server port binding, conflicts may occur as
  'winnat' dynamically manages the translation of private IP addresses
  to public ones, impacting the binding process.
- **Dynamic Service Interaction:**
  Temporarily stopping 'winnat' dynamically modifies the state of the NAT service. This is a strategic measure to create a temporary
  window during which the Node.js server can bind to the port without
  contention from the NAT service.
- **Temporary Network Adjustment:**
  The command net stop winnat instructs Windows to temporarily suspend  the NAT service. This suspension is a tactical maneuver to
  provide a brief opportunity for the Node.js server to bind to the
  port without encountering permission issues.
- **Node.js Server Binding Attempt:**
  With 'winnat' temporarily halted, the Node.js server can successfully bind to the desired port. This step is critical in
  ensuring that the server can initiate and establish connections
  without being denied due to insufficient permissions.
- **Network State Restoration:**
  The subsequent command net start winnat restarts the 'winnat' service, restoring normal network functionality. This ensures that
  any temporary adjustments made for the server binding process are
  reverted, preventing potential disruptions to other network-dependent
  processes.

This sequence of commands is intricately designed to navigate the complexities of Windows services, specifically addressing the challenges posed by the 'winnat' service during the process of binding a Node.js server to a port.

Comment: Why and how does this work?

Comment: It's akin to momentarily pausing a dynamic process to give our server a 'window of opportunity' to claim the port without competition.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Windows changed it default dynamic port range.

You can use this command to check your dynamic port range

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
```

If the port you want to use is within the range, you can change it with this command

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=10000 num=10000
```

You can change the start port number and the number of port you want.

Don't forget to reboot your computer after change.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the port is being used by some other program. Try running the termianl as an admin and try restarting the system. If the issue still persists find a way to kill the process running on the port.