# is there a way to resolve listen EACCES: persmission denied in IIS using nodejs?

Tags: iis, iis-express, iisnode

I am Hosting Nodejs server using IIS using my IP address.
this is how I am configuring my website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYl5B.png)

when I browse the website it is throwing an error quoting:
`Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3001`

how to resolve this ?
I have tried changing port number but the problem still persist.

Comment: [Does the link useful to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70812095/7687666)

Comment: As long as you dump iisnode, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/